# How to copy cell value ONLY to another cell in other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

In order to bypass circular reference in excel, I'm thinking to copy and paste the calculated value (ONLY the value) to another cell in another worksheet every time the value is recalculated.
I guess it's possible only by VBA. Unfortunately, I could not come up with any code that worked for me.
I'll be happy to have ideas.
Thank you.

[edited]
the code I tried:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").MergeArea.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried please?

Comment: Do you want to copy even if the re-calculation has the same results as before??

Comment: @SJR pls see edited post

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I don't mind if its returns the same result

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code into the code window for "Sheet1"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

this code will run anytime there is a change made on "Sheet1" and will place only the value (not the formula) into the cell "B2" on "Sheet2"

Comment: This can be approved upon by checking the `Intersect` rather the `Address`. More standard way to this

Comment: @Glenn G - 
Thank you very much for your answer.
I can’t get this work yet. Potential problems I can assume:
1. I have already `Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)` 
I tried to combine your code into this, with no success.
2. I put `Option Explicit` in the top of the page, but I get an error message from other Private Sub: “Compile error, Variable not defined.”
3. `$A$1` cell is a merged cell. The actual range in my case is `AD26:AF26`

Comment: @MrHalili - the error message "Compile error, Variable not defined." means that you are using a variable somewhere in your code that is not defined. Variables are defined as such: `Dim [Variable] As [Type]`.  Is it possible to post the code that you have already?

Comment: Sure.  I would ask that you consider making a copy of your code and removing as much private/confidential/sensitive information as possible while still providing enough info for someone to be able to help.

Comment: @GlennG, No problem. How should I send it to you?

Comment: @Mr Halili - jreg78-help@yahoo.com
I will of course need to update my answer with as much information as possible without violating any confidential/sensitivity concerns so that others will be able to learn when they search for similar issues.

Comment: @GlennG - I've sent it to you. No worry about sensitive code. Thank you very much!